Gmail markup (google-schema) rejected - JSON-LD
We have added email schemas to our order confirmation email and test it using email markup tester then it shows no errors
when we send it to registertion processs it always rejectd by google schemas review team. here is the sample code that we have added to our emails.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        /* Your CSS styles */
    </style>

    <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "Order",
            "merchant": {
                "@type": "Organization",
                "name": "Name"
            },
            "orderNumber": "111716",
            "orderStatus": "http://schema.org/OrderProcessing",
            "priceCurrency": "USD",
            "price": "404",
            "priceSpecification": {
                "@type": "PriceSpecification",
                "validFrom": "2024-04-05T00:00:00-0800"
            },
            "acceptedOffer": {
                "@type": "Offer",
                "itemOffered": {
                    "@type": "Product",
                    "name": "Heavy Duty Mobility Scooter",
                    "sku": "HDM00052",
                    "url": "test-data",
                    "image": "test-data"
                },
                "price": "385.00",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "eligibleQuantity": {
                    "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            },
            "url": "",
            "potentialAction": {
                "@type": "ViewAction",
                "url": "test-data",
                "name": "View order"
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body style="background: #f8f8f8;">
    <!-- Your HTML content -->
</body>

</html>

When we send them to google whitelisting for approval we get a mail with below reply.
1.No structured data present.
Can someone explain to me why is it always rejected from the review process?

Google has 2 services: Schema Markup Validator (SMV) and Rich Snippets (RS). Your JSON-LD is SMV valid. However, it uses @type specifications that are not RS valid. You can see the response here: https://search.google.com/test/rich-results
You may need to find an SMV-subset that is RS-valid to work in your Gmail markup.

I used Email Markup Tester (https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) tool that has been recommended by Google.  But it doesn't show any error

make sure that script tags are not being stripped somewhere in the process, try moving it to the body, or maybe converting to microdata
